# javascript attached click event issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to setup a `click` event to a `<a>` tag inside a `TD`

I have

```
test.prototype.buildData = function() {
 cell = createElement('td', {innerHTML: "<a class='link' onclick='"+this.edit(this)+"'>"+ value + "</a>"});
 this.table.appendChild(cell);

 //many cells..all need to attached the click event

}

test.prototype.edit=function(this){
  this.style.backgroundColor='red'  
}
```

I want to modify the clicked `cell` `background color`. I also need to register `click` event ONLY to the `<a>` tag. I know my `this.edit(this)` doesn't make sense.

Are there anyways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: First off... don't use onclick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines...

```
test.prototype.buildData = function (value) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td"),
        anchor = document.createElement("a");

    anchor.className = "link";
    anchor.addEventListener("click", (function (self) {
        return function () {
            self.edit(this);
        };
    })(this), false);
    anchor.innerHTML = value;

    cell.appendChild(anchor);

    this.table.appendChild(cell);
};

test.prototype.edit = function (el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
```

NOTES:

1. When you assign a function as an event handler via the `addEventListener` method, the value of `this` within the function is the DOM element that triggered the event.
2. The second argument for `addEventListener` is a function which is simply an object like everything else in JavaScript. Therefore, you can use an immediately invoked function expression that returns a function that would contain the actual event handling code.
3. The value of `this` can be tricky if you're new to JavaScript. If you look at my IIFE which is the function defined inside the parentheses right after the "click" argument for the `addEventListener` method you'll note that I'm passing `this` in as an argument to that at the end (right before the `false` argument). What I'm doing here is passing the value of `this` from the perspective of the `buildData` method which equates to `test.prototype`. The IIFE sees that as the `self` argument, though, so in the returned function it calls `self`'s (i.e. `test.prototype`) `edit` method with the argument `this` which is in this case the element that triggered the event.
4. `test.prototype.edit` takes an element as its single argument and changes the background color.

Answer (score 1):

You could automatically assign ids to the `<a>`-s as you create them

```
var newCellId = 0;
test.prototype.buildData = function() {
  cell = createElement('td',
   {innerHTML: "<a class='link' id='dynamicCellId_"+String(newCellId)+"'"+     value + "</a>"});
  this.table.appendChild(cell);
  newCellId +=1;
}
```

Then you can trace all of them using `document.getElementById('dynamicCellId_X')`